# Android Studio - bulk/mass renaming string resources

Tags: android, string, android-studio, rename, batch-rename

I need to add a prefix to every string resource in my `strings.xml` files

Is there a way of doing this without having to rename the strings one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a dedicated functionality for that type of action.

HOWEVER..

One thing that did make this a bit faster was the **Resource Editor** - it does the job faster than conventional *"Refactor -> Rename"*. It works just like a database editor and proved to be quite handy.